# Ko template with for each to repeat the same drop down in the loop

Tags: knockout.js

I want to place the same Dropdown inside the `data-bind ="foreach :list"`  with ko.
I am not getting the possible solution. May I get the sample code for the same.

For e.g. I have 5 names in people (collection) like

```
<select data-bind="for-each:people", optionText:'Name' , value = 'Id'> </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, you have similar to this structure like

```
<div data-bind="foreach:list">
   .....
   <select data-bind="for-each:people", optionText:'Name' , value = 'Id'> </select>
   .....
</div>
```

and in every `item of list` contains a property `people` which is an (Observables)Array. than you should try this

```
<select data-bind="options:people, optionsText:'Name', optionsValue:'Id'"></select>
```

Comment: IF I have 5 items in the List , then I need to Populate the dropdown list with all the items (5 items) for 5 times using for each

Comment: <div data-bind: foreach :queryDataComputed><select data-bind="options: queryDataComputed, value: selectedAttribute,optionsText: 'AttributeName', optionsCaption: 'Select Attribute...'"></select> </div> but cannot get the UI in place